# Running rails 3.2.13 but have not installed it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, gemfile

Whenever I run:

```
rails -v
```

I get the result

```
rails 3.2.13
```

But my gemfile is as follows:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.12'
gem 'rake' , '~> 10.0.4'
```

My gemfile.lock also has 3.2.12, but for some reason when I check the verison I have 3.2.13 installed. I think this is the reason that every time I try to run  my server I get the error:

Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Can anyone tell me why I am running rails 3.2.13? I want to be running 3.2.12 as my technician has told me there is still problems with 2.13 and I need to stick with 2.12.

Also can anyone tell me why I am getting the rake error, when i have already installed the rake gem and it is in my gemfile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From **[the documentation](http://gembundler.com/v1.3/gemfile.html)**:

> The specifier `~>` has a special meaning, best shown by example. `~> 2.0.3` is identical to `>= 2.0.3` and `< 2.1`. `~> 2.1` is identical to `>= 2.1` and `< 3.0`. `~> 2.2.beta` will match prerelease versions like `2.2.beta.12`.

This means that

```
gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.12'
```

is identical to `>= 3.2.12` and `< 3.3` which means having `3.2.13` installed is perfectly reasonable and acceptable according to your `Gemfile`.

If you want `3.2.12` **and only `3.2.12`**, you must specify this

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
```

Comment: He said rails 2.3.12 is in his Gemfile.lock -- doesn't this mean, that bundler actually uses 2.3.12 (and not 2.3.13)?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have multiple rails versions (2.3.12 and 2.3.13) installed. Do a

```
gem list | grep rails
```

to verify it.

If this is the case, run your command with the `bundle exec` prefix. Using `bundle exec` the bundler gem looks at your Gemfile and makes only those gems available for the following command, which are specified in the Gemfile.

This way

```
bundle exec rails -v
```

should give you `rails 3.2.12`

Answer (score 0):

try , `gem update rake`  or

install the bundle : `bundle install`  in project root path